# Run-time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable "primes" was corrupted

Tags: c++, arrays, runtime-error

I have looked at almost all the other Run-time Check Failure #2 problems, and only 1 has applied the error to the same location I have as in my program. The error, as commented, occurs after I end main(). I am not allocating past the end of the array, and am not changing anything after main has returned.

```
#include <iostream>

void findPrimes(bool primes[], const int arrSize);
int main(){
    const int arrSize = 1000;
    bool primes[arrSize];
    for (int x = 0; x < arrSize; x++){
        primes[x] = true;
    }
    findPrimes(primes, arrSize); //sets all non-prime numbers to false
    for (int x = 0; x < arrSize; x++){ //I did not go past the size of the array.
        if (primes[x]){
            std::cout << x << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0; //Error occurs after this point.
}

void findPrimes(bool primes[], const int arrSize){ //detects and changes non-prime numbers to false
    int temp;
    for (int x = 2; x < arrSize; x++){
        temp = x + x;
        for (int c = 0; c < arrSize; c++){
            if (temp > arrSize){
                break;
            }
            primes[temp] = false;
            temp += x;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test

```
if (temp > arrSize){
        break;
}
```

is on the right track to make sure you don't overrun the array bounds, but there's an off-by-one error because the index `arrSize` isn't a valid array index but won't cause the loop to `break` at this point. Change this to read

```
if (temp >= arrSize){
        break;
}
```

and see if that fixes things.

Comment: Thank you so much, I completely blew past that part when I was looking it over. It works 100% now.